# How to print all fields containing one of two strings in a table with awk

Tags: awk

I have a table with many rows and a variable number of columns per row.

In each row, I only want to print the first field and all the fields containing one of two strings (in this example, I want all fields containing the words dog and cow).

For example:

```
A   dog999   dog284   cow284   pig383   pig234   cow432   chicken432
B   cow394   cow432   cow345   dog983   pig345   chicken532 
C   dog847   pig357   pig236   cow395   dog496
D   dog392   cow237   cow749
```

Desired output:

```
A   dog999   dog284   cow284   cow432   
B   cow394   cow432   cow345   dog983   
C   dog847   cow395   dog496
D   dog392   cow237   cow749
```

So far with awk I have:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /dog/) print $1,$i; else if ($i ~ /cow/) print $1,$i} }' file.txt
```

But that results in one line for every field that contains one of those two strings.

Comment: Use `printf` instead of print and add `print ""` outside of  your loop.

Answer (score 3):

If `perl` solution is fine:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
A   dog999   dog284   cow284   pig383   pig234   cow432   chicken432
B   cow394   cow432   cow345   dog983   pig345   chicken532 
C   dog847   pig357   pig236   cow395   dog496
D   dog392   cow237   cow749

$ perl -lane 'print join("\t",$F[0],grep {/cow|dog/} @F[1..$#F])' ip.txt 
A   dog999  dog284  cow284  cow432
B   cow394  cow432  cow345  dog983
C   dog847  cow395  dog496
D   dog392  cow237  cow749
```

- `-a` split input line on spaces and save to `@F` array
- `-l` strip newlines from input and add back when printing
- `join` will add a `\t` between elements when printing
- `$F[0],grep {/cow|dog/} @F[1..$#F]` first element of array and all elements matching `cow` or `dog`
- Can also use `perl -lape'$_=join"\t",shift(@F),grep/cow|dog/,@F'`. here `shift` will delete and return first element of `@F` array, assigning result to `$_` will get printed at end courtesy `-p` option (Tip of hat to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas))

If lines not containing `cow` or `dog` are to be ignored:

```
perl -lane 'print join("\t",$F[0],grep {//} @F[1..$#F]) if /cow|dog/' ip.txt
```

Comment: Or `perl -lape'$_=join"\t",shift(@F),grep/cow|dog/,@F'` if we want to golf it.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you needed to extract the first value, 'cos you don't want to print that for each matching word.  We can use `printf` to avoid newlines.

```
awk '{printf "%s",$1
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      {
        if ($i ~ /dog|cow/) { printf " %s",$i; }
      }
      print ""
     }'
```

The output would be:

```
A dog999 dog284 cow284 cow432
B cow394 cow432 cow345 dog983
C dog847 cow395 dog496
D dog392 cow237 cow749
```

This can be collapsed to one line:

```
awk '{printf "%s",$1; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /dog|cow/) { printf " %s",$i; }  } print ""  }'
```

Note that this will print a line that doesn't match any words
eg

```
E pig sheep
```

will output

```
E
```

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) [awk macro](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#TOC-9.41):

```
$ txr -e '(awk (:let tmp)
               (:begin (set ofs "\t"))                     
               (f (set tmp (pop f))
                  (ff (keep-if #/cow|dog/))
                  (push tmp f) (prn)))' data
A   dog999  dog284  cow284  cow432
B   cow394  cow432  cow345  dog983
C   dog847  cow395  dog496
D   dog392  cow237  cow749
```

Breakdown:

1. The `:let` clause in the macro specifies local variables. This macro implements the "Awk Paradigm" but in a type-safe language, in which variables have to be defined before use. So in addition to clauses like `:begin` and `:end` (analogous to `BEGIN` and `END` in POSIX Awk), this Awk provides `:let` for defining variables that are lexically scoped to the macro.
2. `(f (set tmp (pop f)) ...)` is a condition-action clause, where the condition is `f`. If is the list of delimited fields from the record; if it is not empty (not equal to `nil`) then it behaves like Boolean true. So the action forms execute if there is anything in `f`.
3. `(set tmp (pop f))` pops the first field from the list and saves it in the temporary variable `tmp`. The second field becomes first, the third second and so on. When we operate on `f`, the record `rec` is also reconstituted automatically using `ofs`, just like in POSIX Awk, the `$0` record is reconstituted using `OFS` between the fields.
4. `(ff ...)` filters the fields through an operation, in this case `(keep-if #/regex/)`. Basically we remove from `f` all the fields that don't match the regex. `ff` is an operator visible inside the `awk` macro. `keep-if` is a regular function; here it is implicitly curried, so the list argument doesn't appear. It expects a predicate function, but a regex is function-callable, so suitable as a predicate.
5. Then we push back the previously saved first field onto the field list `f` with `(push tmp f)`.
6. `(prn)` is the equivalent of `print`. With no arguments, it prints the record, followed by the output record separator (`ors`) which is initialized to newline. Since `rec` has been reconstituted after all the manipulations of `f`, we get the filtered output.

As can be seen, the Awk paradigm is basically intact, just in the context of a different language in which different kinds of things are possible. The convenience of just being able to do `$2 > $1` without checking that these fields actually exists is not there; but on the other hand, we don't have to write loops to process the fields as a data structure. Fields can be mapped through functions or treated as a stack.

Sundeep's Perl solution roughly translates to the `awk` macro like this:

```
$ txr -e '(awk (t (prn `@[f 0]\t@{(keep-if #/cow|dog/ [f 1..:]) "\t"}`)))' data
```