# Using an awk script, how do I count the number of fields in which a substring lies in a file?

Tags: linux, awk, files

For example, I have the text document:

```
"Hello, I am the janitor and I have a headache
 The rabbit jumped over the red brick wall"
```

I want to count the number of fields in which the substring 'he' occurs.   I do not want to count the number of 'he' in the file, just the number of fields.

So for my example, it should print something like this out:

```
Number of fields that contain 'he' in record #1: 3
Number of fields that contain 'he' in record #2: 2
```

It has to be an awk script.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the following script: "{print "Number of fields in record #" NR " containing 'he': " index($0, "he")} and it doesn't work.   I also tried gsub, but gsub counts every occurrence of 'he', not just the fields in which 'he' is found.

Comment: You need to iterate over the fields. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960364/looping-through-fields-in-awk) should help you.

Comment: Have you abandoned https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550529/how-to-add-number-of-fields-throughout-file-together ?

Comment: @JohnMike also, please put your attempts & their results [into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/550554/edit), where they won't be overlooked.

Comment: Yes, essentially, I was abandoning it.   The homework is due in a couple of hours, and I can't afford to figure it out on my own right now.   I've been trying for a day already, and I can't waste any more time.   The other one got answered so quickly by Stephen Kitt, I figured he would help me out with this one too.

Comment: Linking in the related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310949/how-to-print-all-fields-containing-one-of-two-strings-in-a-table-with-awk?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The fields are numbered starting from `1`, and `NF` contains the number of them.
So we can iterate over them with `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { ... }`, with `$i` inside the loop referring to the field in question. (`i` is actually just the number of the field, we need the `$` operator to get the actual contents of the field.)

And as for finding if a value contains a particular substring, using a regex is easiest. `s ~ /foo/` would see if the variable `s` matches the string `foo` anywhere, i.e. if it contains it as a substring. Now, you may also want to also match an uppercase letter, in which case e.g. `[Ff]` would work in place of the `f`. The bracket group `[...]` matches any one of the characters inside.

Of course you'll also need a counter, but that's easy, just initialize a variable to zero before the loop (e.g. `count=0`) and increment if there's a match (`count += 1`).

~ ~

So, basically, an awk script to run some code for each line/record of a file is just

```
awk '{ some code }' < filename.txt
```

Inside the code block, the `for` loop fits, and it also takes a block in braces `{ .. }`.

```
awk '{ for ( ... ) { some code } }`
```

And an `if` works similarly,

```
if (condition) { some code... }
```

(They actually look just like `for` and `if` in C.)

And you can use semicolons to separate statements, so

```
awk '{ what to do before the loop; for ( ... ) { some code }; what to do after }`
```

Comment: what would that look like as a complete script file though?   I'm at a complete loss.   Our professor didn't talk about this stuff.

Comment: @JohnMike, well, that's just the thing, I really hate to give complete answers for homework. That should be about all the pieces, though, if you have the time to try to build something out of them.

Comment: I don't, and I normally wouldn't ask for complete answers, but I am worried about getting an A in this class.   I'm a straight A student, and usually have no problem with my comp sci classes, but this professor is notorious for expecting out-of-class knowledge.   I've never used unix/linux before, and I am really struggling here.   The homework consists of 20 problems, and these 3, plus 2 in another post I made, are the only ones I can't figure out.   I am running out of time, it's due by tomorrow.

Comment: @JohnMike, try if you can get some pieces together? SE sucks for interactive back-and-forth debugging, but you can edit your Q to add a script if you get a step or two forward, and then we can see what's the stopper

Comment: @JohnMike Considering (a) the way shown here to iterate over the fiels of each record using for loop, (b) `gsub` that you have tried in your abandoned post can accept a target to perform i.e `gsub("he","",$i)`  (c) you have a basic comp sci background (d) you can use online tools like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php to make your homework even if you have not linux in your pc , then there is not any strong excuse not to try to solve your homework with the help given here. At least make a try , and help will arrive.

Comment: I have no basic comp sci background, this and another class this semester are my first classes ever in comp sci.

Comment: Using `tolower` on the record before pattern matching could be an alternative to considering cases in the regex. Of course it depends if you are searching for `he` or `goodlordisthisalongstring`.

Answer (score 1):

Done by below awk script

```
awk -v i="he" '{print "Number of fields that contain" " " i " " gsub("he",$0) " " "in record " NR}' file
```

output

```
Number of fields that contain he 3 in record 1
Number of fields that contain he 2 in record 2
```